# How many different positive integer factors does have?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

How many different positive integer factors does $(2^7)(3^4)(7^3)(23^5)$ have?

Do we have to do any combinations between the powers here?

Comment: $8\times 5\times 4\times 6$

Comment: Well there's 4 answers all saying the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is *the number of the positive divisors* of $2^7\cdot 3^4\cdot 7^3\cdot 23^5$. Then, the answer is
$$(7+1)(4+1)(3+1)(5+1)=8\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 6=960.$$

In general, if
$$N={p_1}^{\color{red}{q_1}}\cdot {p_2}^{\color{red}{q_2}}\cdots {p_k}^{\color{red}{q_k}}$$
where $q_i,k\in\mathbb N$ and $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_k$ are primes, then *the number of the positive divisors of $N$* can be represented as
$$(\color{red}{q_1}+1)(\color{red}{q_2}+1)\cdots (\color{red}{q_k}+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Is all the numbers of the form $2^n3^m7^k35^\ell$ with $n\in\{0,...,7\}, m\in\{0,...,4\},k\in\{0,...,3\}$ and $\ell\in\{0,...,5\}$ and that gives $8\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 6$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if

$$n = p_1^{\alpha_1}·p_2^{\alpha_2}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$

Then the amount of positive divisors of $n$ is:

$$d(n) = (\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)\ldots (\alpha_k+1)$$

In your case, it has $(7+1)(4+1)(3+1)(5+1) = 8·5·4·6 = 960$

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:

- $\gcd(2,3)=1$
- $\gcd(2,7)=1$
- $\gcd(2,23)=1$
- $\gcd(3,7)=1$
- $\gcd(3,23)=1$
- $\gcd(7,23)=1$

Therefore, the number of different positive integer divisors of $(2^7)(3^4)(7^3)(23^5)$ is:

$$(7+1)\cdot(4+1)\cdot(3+1)\cdot(5+1)=960$$